# Create cookie by javascript and read it from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I am developing a website in which i want to create a cookie from JavaScript  and read it's value from Node.js server.

Please give some code..

Comment: On client side create cookies with [Cookies](https://github.com/ScottHamper/Cookies) library and on node.js server use [cookie-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) to populate `req.cookies` and work with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JavaScript, a cookie can be created like this:

```
document.cookie = "username=Vivek Singh";
```

With NodeJs, Below code could help since there is no quick function to access cookies,

```
var getCookies = function(request) {
  var cookies = {};
  request.headers && request.headers.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(cookie) {
    var parts = cookie.match(/(.*?)=(.*)$/)
    cookies[ parts[1].trim() ] = (parts[2] || '').trim();
  });
  return cookies;
};
```

Then, to get a specific cookie simply call this method:

```
getCookies (request)['username']
```

Comment: @RohitKumar thanks. Please accept the answer if that helps.